# Translating binary code to Assembler and vice versa in C++? (Library, Metamophing)

Tags: c++, assembly, compilation, binary

How can I translate a binary file into assembly code and vice versa? I want to metamorph executables or dlls by changing the assembly code and assemble it back to machine language. I'm looking for a library, because I don't want to change every asm command by hand.

Example:
I want to change:

```
mov eax, ecx
```

into

```
push ecx
pop eax
```

Comment: are you looking for a disassembler?

Comment: Yes and for a assembler too. But a library, not a program like Olly or IDA.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called a **disassembler**. Normally they also come with a debugger. One commonly used is [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/). For static analysis I recommend you [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml). Notice however that IDA isnt free.

Both are able to patch executables too.

EDIT:
As you apparently look for a library (please be more precisely next time), notice that OllyDbg is open source and you can therefor easily access its non-GUI parts. See: [OllyDbg Source Description](http://www.ollydbg.de/srcdescr.htm)

Comment: Thank's for your answear. But I'm looking for a Library. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @MazzMan IDA features scripting and can accomplish your usecase.

Comment: I get tonns of errors with the OllyDbg source code, because there are so many deprecated functions.